# How to redirect in Plugin.php

Tags: pimcore

I need quick tip:
how to redirect to plugn's controller from plugins/MyPlugin/lib/MyPlugin/Plugin.php
?

I know that 
`header("Location:http://example.com");`
probably works, but mayby is sth better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this:

```
$redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
$redirector->gotoSimpleAndExit('action','controller','default');
```